# Can my lemons grow in cactus soil mix

Tags: soil, cactus, lemons

I bought cactus soil mix the other day from Calloway's for some plants. I then decided to grow lemons. So I did the whole deal. 2 weeks later I have lemon sprouts. I was wondering if I could use cactus soil mix for baby lemon seeds that already have some 1 inch sized roots.

Comment: I wouldn't transplant citrus bareroot until the stem has hardened. Cactus mix is great for *germinating* citrus and other seeds, but they will prefer a more water retentive mix later in life.

Comment: Oh, I meant I just had the seeds in a bag, with a damp paper towel, in a dark warm spot! For 2 weeks.

Comment: So go ahead and use this soil to get your seed started.  Use starting pots 2" diameter made of peat or plastic with drainage holes, fill with this sandier than normal potting soil and start your seeds.  Be just fine.  When they get large enough and their roots grow below the pot upgrade to a 4" pot.  You should then be using potting soil without all the sand for cactus. What kind of environment are we talking about?  Indoors, outdoors, on a patio?    Where is it that you live?  When your lemons outgrow the 4" pots upgrade to 6".  Next will be a 2 gallon pot....what are your plans?